# Invalid regular expression in d3.v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.v5 and in a project that used to work, I now get the following exception:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^|\s+/: Stack overflow
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at String.split (legacy.js:10)
    at parseTypenames (VM66 d3.v5.js:751)
    at Dispatch.on (VM66 d3.v5.js:763)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (VM66 d3.v5.js:3667)
    at Transition.selection_each [as each] (VM66 d3.v5.js:1185)
    at Transition.transition_on [as on] (VM66 d3.v5.js:3678)
    at Transition.transition_remove [as remove] (VM66 d3.v5.js:3690)
    at axis (VM66 d3.v5.js:653)
    at Transition.selection_call [as call] (VM66 d3.v5.js:1149)
```

The code that hits is:

```
return typenames.trim().split(/^|\s+/).map(function(t) {
    var name = "", i = t.indexOf(".");
    if (i >= 0) name = t.slice(i + 1), t = t.slice(0, i);
    if (t && !types.hasOwnProperty(t)) throw new Error("unknown type: " + t);
    return {type: t, name: name};
  });
}
```

Seems like **split(/^|\s+/)** breaks Chrome.

I do not understand how this used to work and now it does not.

Any fix for this?

Comment: How can you split a string on `string start (^)` or do you want to split in individual lines? `split(/[\s\n\r]+/)`

Comment: @rioV8 I don't understand that `^` either, but `\s` [already considers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) `\n` and `\r`. About the issue at hand, this `parseTypenames` function doesn't look like a stack overflow pitfall unless `typenames` is huge (really huge), so maybe it's the way it's called: if it's part of a (bad) recursive process, it might end up like this.

Comment: Actually just tested the regex with "a b c" and 1 million spaces between each characters: works like a charm in no time. Also tested on a Web page that made the `split` provide a 5k+ array. So, to me, it seems very likely that the error is in the caller process, and the stack just happens to overflow at this point.

Comment: @StockOverflaw: now I looked a bit more closely and it involves parsing the transition `start.abcd` names because you can have multiple handlers for the same event. Most likely @elena calls `transition.on()` the wrong way and a lot. **We need the app code not the d3 code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stock Overflaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269732/stock-overflaw)  was right:

> it seems very likely that the error is in the caller process, and the stack just happens to overflow at this point.

The error was in the caller process in a javascript.
Instead of a delegate in a tick method that calls itself, I have passed the function directly. So I had an endless loop and a stack that was becoming huge.

Wrong:

```
.on("end", tick(myParam));
```

Right with delegate:

```
.on("end", function () { tick(myParam); });
```

Thanks for your help!